# Docker compose to always deploy using latest image

Tags: docker-compose

I have searched around and found some similar questions, but no answer seemed to clarify completely.

Scenario: Newer images keep getting pushed to the concerned Docker registry. 
I want to use docker-compose to always pull the latest image from the registry and then replace the existing running container on the Docker host with a new container deployed from that latest image.

Is just executing 'docker-compose up -d' enough? 
Or do I need to do a 'docker-compose pull' or any other step before that?

Answer (score 10):

You won't pull new service images just running this command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

If you need to always check for a newer image and use it this command should work for you:

```
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d
```